# typescript - get type by indexing object interface with variable

Tags: typescript, dynamictype

Hi I would like to index object interface with a variable

so heres my interfaces:

```
interface OptionsRedux {
  default_route: DefaultRoute[];
  insurance_company: InsuranceCompany[];
  marital_status: MaritalStatus[];
  reason: Reason[];
  termination_reason: TerminationReason[];
}
type optionGroupTypes = keyof OptionsRedux;
```

Right now my code looks like this:

```
interface GetOptions {
  type: ActionTypes.getOptions,
  payload: {group: optionGroupTypes, values: OptionsRedux[optionGroupTypes]}
}
export const getOptions = (
  group: optionGroupTypes,
  values: OptionsRedux[optionGroupTypes]
): GetOptions => ({
  type: ActionTypes.getOptions,
  payload: { group, values },
});
```

which gives me type for payload value:

```
DefaultRoute[] | InsuranceCompany[] | MaritalStatus[] | Reason[] | TerminationReason[]
```

but I would like to do something like this:

```
interface GetOptions {
  type: ActionTypes.getOptions,
  payload: {group: optionGroupTypes, values: OptionsRedux[group]}
}
```

this gives me that the group is undefined.

my objective is, that when I would use function getOption("default_route", values), the values would have to be:

```
DefaultRoute[]
```

Any ideas? cant find anything that would work

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with generics.  To expand on your examples:

```js
interface GetOptions<T extends optionGroupTypes> {
  type: ActionTypes.getOptions,
  payload: { group: T, values: OptionsRedux[T] }
}

export const getOptions = <T extends optionGroupTypes>(
  group: T,
  values: OptionsRedux[T]
): GetOptions<T> => ({
  type: ActionTypes.getOptions,
  payload: { group, values },
});
```

By adding the generic type `T`, the `group` and `values` types are kept in sync with each other.  `T` is the specific chosen type, rather than the union of all the types.

Answer (score -1):

**This is the right way to create a partial interface**

```
interface IPerson {
firstname: string,
lastname: string,
[key: string]: any
}
```

**Create an object of type IPerson**

```
const person: IPerson {
firstname: 'John',
lastname: 'Doe',
phonenummber: 82184
}
```

I hope this will help you